# Getting a column id from the username or business name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get the id of the user through the username posted and the id of the business through the id as well and store there ids in the database. Can i look them up by find_by and store the query in a variable then get the id using .id. Not sure if they is the correct probably not the way.

```
module Api
  module V1
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :json

      def new
        @subscriptions = Subscriptions.new
      end
      def create

        user = User.find_by_username(params[:username_id])

        business = Business.find_by_name(params[:business_id])

        @subscriptions = Subscriptions.new(user.id business.id)

          respond_to do |format|
            if @subscriptions.save
              format.json { render json: "Status:Created"}
            else
              format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
      end
      private
        def user_params
          params.require(:subscriptions).permit(:username_id, :business_id)
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I doubt you have something called `username_id` coming in. You should look at what `params` actually contains.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and stick a new line between your methods. Reading a block of code this size without blank lines is not idiomatic Ruby, and arguably not pleasant.

Comment: @user3882976 you want to put new lines between your methods. There's no issue in putting them inside methods too when they get too long. But `new` and `create` are different and do different things. Not having blank lines between them makes for less readable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors in your code. Let's assuming the information you provided is correct, what you need to do is fairly trivial.

First, the following line is not correct Ruby. There is no coma between your arguments, and `new` accepts a hash.

```
@subscriptions = Subscriptions.new(user.id business.id)
```

You need to pass in the attributes like this:

```
@subscriptions = Subscriptions.new(user_id: user.id, business: business.id)
```

Normally you would want to use strong_parameters, but since in this case you are defining the keys in the `new` method, you can skip `strong_parameters` all together. You only need it if you pass hash object, instead of individual keys like I showed you above.

You have already defined a method called `user_params`, but you are not using it, and you are saving a subscription object. If you were using `strong_parameters`, you want to rename that method and use it.

```
@subscriptions = Subscriptions.new(subscription_params)
def subscription_params
  # notice :subscription in singular, and not in plural
  params.require(:subscription).permit(:user_id, :business_id)
end
```

This probably still won't work if the params do not map to your database object, as hinted at by @meager in his comment. So you want to check the params hash. I would raise an error with its contents to see what params you are receiving.

```
raise params.to_yaml
```

Finally, if you are using Rails 4, you must use the correct finders. `find_by_col_name` is deprecated. Use instead `find_by(attribute: value)`. So:

```
user = User.find_by(username_id: params[:username_id])
```

Do the same thing for the Business object.

Comment: @user3882976 you're welcome. I updated my answer because there was a factual mistake and a some thing else that needed changing.